# How to browse to data source for connectionstring in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am programming something for users to create a pivot table based on a Access db file. Everything works as desired, except one thing. i want my users to browse to the Access file to use as Data Source.

```
cnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\xxx.accdb;Mode=Read;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sAccessFileName As String

sAccessFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Access Files (*.mdb; *.accdb), (*.mdb; *.accdb), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)

cnString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & sAccessFileName & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need.